# Pivot table display

Tags: sql

I have some data as shown below

```
ItemCode      Attr1    Attr1  InStock
ITEM-000001   43      S      1
ITEM-000001   52      L    2
ITEM-000006   42      R    1
ITEM-000006   44      R    2
ITEM-000009   56      R    1
ITEM-000011   40      R    2
```

And by using Pivot table (or any other technique) I want the result like as

```
Output for ITEM-000001
     43   52

S    1    
L         2
```

Same for others.

Comment: Important question: How much similarity/overlap is there between each of the items in terms of the values for the Attr1 and Attr2 columns?

Comment: That will be changed, actually you can consider it as the Shirts size it will be as 38, 39... and so with Attribute2 as (S-Small, L-Large & R-Regular, X, XL, XXL)

Is that helpful?

Comment: Yes, that's actually very important; because without reasonable overlap, the pivot query wouldn't be that useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you rather write your query to go for the following layout, and use a reporting tool to finalise the output as you have shown. Most reporting tools should have little trouble pulling the ItemCode column into a section heading.

```
                   42   43   44   52   56
ITEM-000001   S         1
ITEM-000001   L                   2
ITEM-000006   R    1         2
ITEM-000009   R                         1
```

The query to create the above layout is as follows:

```
SELECT  ItemCode, Attr2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Attr1=42 THEN InStock ELSE 0 END) AS S42,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Attr1=43 THEN InStock ELSE 0 END) AS S43,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Attr1=44 THEN InStock ELSE 0 END) AS S44,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Attr1=52 THEN InStock ELSE 0 END) AS S52,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Attr1=56 THEN InStock ELSE 0 END) AS S56
FROM    StockData
GROUP BY ItemCode, Attr2
```

### EDIT

If there is insufficient consistency in the values of Attr1 and Attr2 to perform a standard pivot on either of those columns, then SQL is not the best tool to solve your problem.
You'll be better off returning the data to a client application, and allowing it to process the information for you. You'll be able to far more easily add arbitrary columns to your result before getting to final out.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but it will not helpful in my case.
Because Attr1 & Attr2 will change (it will be any number or text)

Comment: That's why I asked you for clarification about the nature of those attributes. :/